# Where to put a text file to be read by Android Studio class

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and I have a project with a class that must open and read a text file. Where should I copy such a text file in order to be found and read successfully? I need to read the text file as follows:

```
File objFile = new File("Sample.txt");
Scanner objScanner = new Scanner(objFile);
while (objScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    // Code to process each line of text file.
}
```

I have seen some posts that suggest to save the text file in the "assets" folder but, where is this folder located?

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: I created an assets folder right clicking on the package and selecting "New / Folder / Assets Folder". I copied my text file here but it is not found by my code.

Comment: In order to access files from asset folder you must use assetmanager as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create project in android studio, then asset folder not created default. You must create asset folder explicitly.

Right click on project root folder --> select New Option --> Select folder--> select asset Folder-->enter

Your asset folder is created and visible to you under app/ and you can put your files here. To read the text file from asset use asset manager. For example .

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
// To load text file
        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = assetManager.open("helloworld.txt");

             int size = input.available();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
             input.read(buffer);
             input.close();

             // byte buffer into a string
             String text = new String(buffer);

             txtContent.setText(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For details about asset manager visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html